# How do i fix this error with my python program?

Tags: python

I tried to subtract a certain variable to make a expected bake time calculator and a error happened.

Here is my code for you all to solve.

```
def EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME():
    EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40

EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME()

def bake_time_remaining():
    bake_time_passed = 15
    bake_time_left = (EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME) - (bake_time_passed)

bake_time_remaining()
```

Here is the error.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'int'

Update: To give more clarity to this, i tried to practice python on Exersicm (Link: https://exercism.org/tracks/python/exercises/guidos-gorgeous-lasagna/edit) And it needs me to do certain things to make it work.

(i can't show pictures because i don't have 10 reputation)

Comment: Please do not name a function and variable the same thing...

Comment: What were you hoping *EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40* would do when you've already defined a function with that name?

Comment: @CtrlZ I'm a beginner at python and i thought it might have worked because i was getting desperate for answers at the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Functions return a value when explicitly specified.

```py
# Functions should explicitly return a value for later use.
def get_expected_bake_time():
    return 40

def bake_time_remaining(bake_time_passed):
    # Use the returned value in the calculation.
    bake_time_left = get_expected_bake_time() - bake_time_passed

# Invoke the function with a value.
bake_time_remaining(15)
```

2. Alternatively, you can use a variable.

```py
EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40

def bake_time_remaining(bake_time_passed):
    # Use a variable in the calculation.
    bake_time_left = EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME - bake_time_passed

# Invoke the function with a value.
bake_time_remaining(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a global variable inside a function, you need to use the `global` keyword.

```py
# Constants
DEFAULT_EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40
BAKE_TIME_INTERVAL = 15

def reset_bake_time():
    global remaining_bake_time
    remaining_bake_time = DEFAULT_EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME

def bake_longer():
    global remaining_bake_time
    remaining_bake_time -= BAKE_TIME_INTERVAL

remaining_bake_time = 0 # Global variable

reset_bake_time()

print(f"Baking for {remaining_bake_time} minutes...")

while remaining_bake_time >= 0:
    bake_longer()
    print(f"~ Time left to bake: {remaining_bake_time} minutes")

if remaining_bake_time < 0:
    print(f"Oops! You overbaked by: {-remaining_bake_time} minutes!")
```

Here is the output:

```
Baking for 40 minutes...
~ Time left to bake: 25 minutes
~ Time left to bake: 10 minutes
~ Time left to bake: -5 minutes
Oops! You overbaked by: 5 minutes!
```

Comment: This is good, but i keep getting this error in the code and i dont know why.                                         MISSING FUNCTION --> In your 'lasagna.py' file, we can not find or import the function named 'preparation_time_in_minutes()'. 
Did you misname or forget to define it?